# Why did the author use sweet instead of dear?

Tags: word-usage

> In her younger days Francesca had been known as the beautiful Miss
>   Greech; at forty, although much of the original beauty remained, she
>   was just dear Francesca Bassington. No one would have dreamed of
>   calling her **sweet**, but a good many people who scarcely knew her were
>   punctilious about putting in the “dear.”

[THE UNBEARABLE BASSINGTON CHAPTER 1](http://haytom.us/the-unbearable-bassington-chapter-1/)

I don't understand this paragraph. Why did the author use sweet instead of dear?

Comment: This is literary interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

'sweet' is often used to mean a nice, soft-spoken person. You would call a person who speaks very nicely, is polite all the time 'sweet' (especially if they were a little girl).

> [7. pleasing or agreeable; delightful.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sweet)

In this case, we can look at the next line:

> Her enemies, in their honester moments, would have admitted that she was svelte and knew how to dress, but they would have agreed with her friends in asserting that she had no soul.

> ***that she had no soul***

This means that she is *not* a nice person. She is not 'sweet' in the sense that she's mean, and not very nice.

> but a good many people who scarcely knew her were punctilious about putting in the “dear.”

From what I can tell, this means that people are trying to keep on her good side - they always make sure to put the 'dear', to make sure that she doesn't get annoyed and stays happy, because... she doesn't seem very nice.

Comment: The last paragraph looks like an opinion or interpretation at best. *No one would have dreamed of calling her sweet, but [...] many people [...] were punctilious about putting in the “dear.”* By my lights, what you're suggesting seems a little wide of the mark since *but* introduces a clause that's in contrast with the previous one. (Sorry for the late reply.)

Comment: I.e., "She's not a paragon of kindness, but she doesn't come across as unpleasant, either."

Comment: @userr2684291 the questions by this user about these texts should all be closed as literary interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because saying *Dear Francesca*, for example, is something determined by custom or formality (e.g. you start a letter with *Dear whoever* but you don't necessarily consider them dear), whereas calling someone *sweet* is done only because you really think they are sweet.